# En ConstraintLayout como centrar los botones?

Tags: android-studio, botón

estoy utilizando **frameLayout (ConstraintLayout)**, donde tengo puesto unos botones y estoy intentando que se queden centrados:

[image: http://funkyimg.com/i/2KWzH.png]

El problema es que cuando el móvil está en vertical se ven bien,

[image: http://funkyimg.com/i/2KWzJ.png]

Pero al ponerlo en horizontal, los botones se separan quedando más espacio entre los botones,

[image: http://funkyimg.com/i/2KWzK.png]

Supongo que, en una pantalla mayor como una Tablet, quedaría más separación entre los botones, como puedo hacer para que queden todos en el centro, pero con la misa distancia entre ellos.

**documentos.xml**

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/frameLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.SoCu.CirDocu.Documentos">


<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="62dp"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:contentDescription="@string/Nombre1"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    android:src="@drawable/imagen"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btCo_A"
    android:layout_width="74dp"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:contentDescription="@string/Nombre2"
    android:drawableStart="@drawable/co_a"
    android:elevation="0dp"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/btCo_EXP"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btCo_C"
    android:layout_width="74dp"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:contentDescription="@string/Nombre3"
    android:drawableStart="@drawable/co_c"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/btCo_P"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btCo_P"
    android:layout_width="74dp"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:contentDescription="@string/Nombre4"
    android:drawableStart="@drawable/con_p"
    android:elevation="0dp"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/btCo_EXP"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/btCo_C"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btCo_EXP"
    android:layout_width="77dp"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:contentDescription="@string/Nombre5"
    android:drawableStart="@drawable/con_exp"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/btCon_A"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/btCo_P"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Gracias.

Comment: Agrega tu layout escrito para así poder ver las propiedades de los botones.

Comment: ya lo he puesto @denifer